# ASP.Net MVC File Upload not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Okay, so I was having a weird file upload problem. I had some code set up like this on the cshtml file.

```
<form method="post" action="~/meme/createcustom2"  id="submitimage" name="submitimage">
        <div class="drag-box">
            <div class="drag">
                <div id="dragandrophandler">
                    <label class="hand">
                        Drag File or
                        Click to Upload&hellip;
                        <input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile">                        </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="or">Or</span>
            <span class="uploadBtn" id="uploadBtn">
                <a href="#" class="btn">UPLOAD <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </span>
            <p>Choose an image from your computer</p>
        </div>
```

And no matter what I did, the file wasn't uploading. I'd see the entry in the Forms collection, but no entry in the Files collection. Well, that vexed me this entire morning.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of questions like this, and most answers suggesting changing the input tag's name attribute, that might help in some cases, but this is not why the problem occurs.

I could find it after a little hunting.

My form tag is missing the following attribute

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

This attribute is needed before the form will accept binary files. Otherwise it only accepts uuencoded text data.

I put that in, and changed my form tag to look like this

```
<form method="post" action="~/meme/createcustom2" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="submitimage" name="submitimage">
```

That solved the problem.

Hope it helps someone.